# Work with timer and background worker at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, timer, backgroundworker

I want to a call a function in a timer tick event so that it executes until the timer interval finishes. The problem is that the function is working with background worker and I cannot set e.Cancel = true to stop the function execution before the time is up. Here is what I've tried.

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    presenter.RunEngine();    // call the function here
    // ...
}

-------------------------------------------------------

public BackgroundWorker worker;

public PresenterClass()
{
   worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
   worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
   worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}

private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   DisplayState();
}

private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   if (worker.CancellationPending)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      worker.ReportProgress(0);
      return;
   }
   worker.RunWorkerAsync();  // I don't think I should call it here, but it doesn't work otherwise
}

public void RunEngine()
{
   if (worker.CancellationPending)
   {
      view.timer.Enabled = false;
      view.timer.Stop();
      // here I should be able to set e.Cancel = true;
      return;
   }
   double oxygenLevel = _systemEngine.Subsystems.Where(s => s.Article == "Oxygen").First().State.Level;
   if (oxygenLevel > 0)
   {
      ConsumeEngine();
   }
   else
   {
      worker.CancelAsync();
   }
}

private void ConsumeEngine()
{
   Parallel.ForEach(_systemEngine.Subsystems, (currentSystem) =>
   {
      if (currentSystem is ShieldMatrix)
      {
         ConsumeShields(currentSystem);
      }
      else if (currentSystem is WeaponToolbar)
      {
         ConsumeWeapons(currentSystem);
      }
      else {
         currentSystem.State.Consume();
      }
    ));
    worker.ReportProgress(90);
    }

private void ConsumeWeapons(BaseModel currentSystem)
{
   // ...
}

private void ConsumeShields(BaseModel currentSystem)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: your code is not proper.

Comment: Could you give some suggestions on how I can make it proper?

Comment: You don't need timer. Measure time intervals during `BackgroundWorker` execution (using `Stopwatch`) and see if you need to wait or do something specific if you exceed given for cycle execution time span.

Comment: There are too many mistakes in how you are using the background worker, don't know how to start. Please read the [documentation on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) how to use a background worker.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that commented that there are better ways of achieve this functionality, but if you still will go ahead with this approach, then you'll need to make the DoWorkEventArgs accessible somehow to RunEngine method. You could for instance declare an instance field an store the args of the background worker before you call the RunWorkerAsync method.

```
    //Declare an instance to store the arguments of the background worker
    public DoWorkEventArgs DoWorkEventArgsIntance { get; set; }


private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            worker.ReportProgress(0);

            //Clear the DoWorkEventArgs intance
            DoWorkEventArgsIntance = null;

            return;
        }

        //Set the instance to the current value of the bw
        DoWorkEventArgsIntance = e;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // I don't think I should call it here, but it doesn't work otherwise
    }
```

Then on the RunEngine method when you need to stop execution you'll have access to the arguments and you'll be able to call Cancel.

```
public void RunEngine()
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            view.timer.Enabled = false;
            view.timer.Stop();

            // here I should be able to set e.Cancel = true;

            //As we stored the value before start the worker, now we can cancel here
            DoWorkEventArgsIntance.Cancel = true;

            return;
        }

        double oxygenLevel = _systemEngine.Subsystems.First(s => s.Article == "Oxygen").State.Level;
        if (oxygenLevel > 0)
        {
            ConsumeEngine();
        }
        else
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help you.